# Updated CSDTService Template and can no longer Use CSDT plugin to save to WCS

Tags: webcenter-sites

I updated the CSDTService element within the ElementCatalog (Path below) in order to add some extra logging to help me identify some other issues I was having saving certain assets I was updating form within Eclispe (using the WCS plugin).

```
ElementCatalog/OpenMarket/Xcelerate/PrologActions/Publish/csdt/CSDTService.jsp
```

Anyway, after this change I don't seem to be able to upload anything else form eclipse!

I put a proxy between elcipse and WCS and tried saving some changes to a template and I can see the request being made, the ping request returns OK but the upload sync from eclipse to WCS returns with :

```
Insufficient Privileges
```

This is the message that you can see within the CSDTService template if your user isn't a member of the "xceladmin" ACL (mine is, see next).

Now, my user has about every right going and was previously working. My user belongs to:

- RESTAdmin group

  Has the following ACLs (and others that I haven't listed):
- xceladmin
- siteGod

Now because I can no longer save anything from Eclipse I can't undo the change. Are there any other ways to revert the template or to figure out what is causing the issue so that I can save to WCS form eclipse?

Appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue and so I thought I would document it here in case anyone else has the same problem.

The essence of the solution is to locate an unaltered version of the template (which I found on another instance of WCS I use) and then to use the CSDT command line tool to upload it.

So the steps were:

- Locate the unaltered template, if you don't have another instance then you could probably locate it by exploding the installation bundle
- Use the CSDT tool to export the broken template to the server file system default workspace (you could use any workspace though)
- Update the exported version of the template with the unaltered version
- Use the CSDT command line tool to upload it

The CSDT command line tool obviously doesn't rely on this template in order to upload. One thing to thing about is that if patches have been applied then the template may have changed and you should try and find the latest, patched version.

Kris

Comment: Worth noting that you can also use SitesExplorer to directly access the Template table (or any table), in case of problems accessing Sites via CSDT.